# Why can't a malicious site obtain a CSRF token via GET before attacking?

Tags: ajax, security, browser, csrf, csrf-protection

If I understand correctly, in a CSRF attack a malicious website **A** tells my browser to send a request to site **B**. My browser will automatically include my **B** cookies in that request. Although **A** cannot see those cookies, if I'm already authenticated in **B** the request will look legit, and whatever action was asked will be successfully performed. To avoid this, every time that I visit a page of **B** containing a form, I receive a CSRF token. This token is associated to my session, so if I make a POST to **B** I MUST include such token; otherwise **B** rejects my request. The benefit of this scheme is that **A** will not have access to that token.

I have two questions:

- Is the above description correct?
- If so, why can't site **A** first tell my browser to send a GET to **B**, obtain the CSRF token from the response, and then use the token to send now a POST to **B**? Notice that the token will be valid and associated to my session, as the GET also contains all my **B** cookies.

Thanks!

Comment: The Same-origin Policy prevents site B from reading content on Site A as the user

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your description is correct.

If site A tells your browser to go to B and get the token, that's fine, but as it is a cross-domain request, A will not have access to the token in Javascript (this is a browser feature). So when A tells your browser to go back to B and actually do something, it still cannot include the token in the request.

That is, unless B set the token as a cookie. Evidently, that would be flawed, because the token cookie would also be sent, thus negating any protection. So the token in this case must be sent as either a form value or a request header (or something else that is not sent automatically like a cookie).

This also means that if B is vulnerable to cross-site scripting, it is also vulnerable to CSRF, because the token can then be stolen, but CSRF is the smaller problem then. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I don't quite understand yet is this "browser feature" (I imagine you refer to CORS). Because there are many sites that perform cross-domain requests, and they can actually look at the content of the response. The most simple example I can think of is the inclusion of an image which src points to a different domain. What I don't get is if the server will send a different Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for images than for pages, or if the browser is taking care of this. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually the feature is called SOP, same origin policy. Javascript only has access to content downloaded from the origin of the page itself, unless the other site sends CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) headers to allow the requestor access. Javascript does not have access to cross-origin images either, but they are displayed to the user. Similarly, another origin can be loaded and displayed in an iframe (unless x-frame-options is sent, but that's a different story), but the outer page will not have access to the iframe contents.

Comment: It's a browser feature. Can an attacker use something else, may be like curl and send request to siteB and fetch csrf token ?

Comment: @v1h5 yes of course, for himself. But would that make sense? No, he would have it in a browser anyway. In CSRF the attacker exploits the existing session of a valid user (victim)  because for example the session cookie is sent automatically. In curl he wouldn't have a valid user.

Comment: @GaborLengyel oh yes! that makes sense. Apologies for lame question. Trying my best to understand all the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

Site A can't get site B's csrf token because of the browser's [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) strategy.

And we need to validate the request's `referer`(It can be forged).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

It is also a good practice to validate the crsf token in url(AKA query string).

FYI,`Laravel`, a popular web framework, uses a hidden CSRF token field in the form to prevent csrf attack.

Comment: I know about the hidden CSRF token, that is precisely what I refer to in my question. So, if I understand correctly, the attack I mention is prevented by telling the server to disallow sending responses containing CSRF tokens to requests from other referrers (which the browser should ensure is correct, right?).

Comment: @Mugarte Bingo.