How to protect CSRF Token API endpoint
I am building a web application with Django and DRF for the backend and RESTful API, and Solidjs for the frontend. Currently, I have my frontend send an API GET request to retrieve the CSRF Token and save it to the context. I realized that anyone could find the API endpoint to retrieve the CSRF Token via the Network tab in the inspect window of their browser, and use that to bypass my website's CSRF protection by sending a GET request to that endpoint using something like Postman or their own custom client or script.
How can I bypass this? I added
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
to my settings.py, but it didn't do anything.

You seem to misunderstand what CSRF is, and what the CSRF token protects against. It does not authenticate your frontend to your backend in the sense you probably want (because that is not possible). Instead, it protects against an attacker exploiting a victim user's session by making the user send inadvertent requests from a malicious origin. (Also I don't understand the downvote, I think this is a perfectly valid question.)

Are you not using Django’s default CSRF protection? A CSRF token is supposed to be tied to a session; attackers being able to read their own CSRF token won’t help them CSRF someone else. (If you have a globally shared “CSRF token” that’s the same for all users, then yeah, that’s not an effective CSRF token, but how did that happen?)

I am using the default django csrf protection, I have a GET view that responds with a CSRF token it generates using the get_token function. I tested it with postman and the token is different every time, but wouldn't attackers be able to make a script that retrieves the token from this endpoint and bypass the protection?

I understand that it doesn't authenticate the user, it is supposed to protect against malicious requests from other sites using the user's cookie data, I'm just afraid that an attacker can find the api endpoint that retrieves the token (as it is not protected and I want to know how I can protect it) and use that token in the malicious request.

Without a separate vulnerability, attackers can’t make authenticated requests as someone else (like the kind required to retrieve a CSRF token corresponding to the session they’re trying to attack) while also being able to read the response. Your question is light on details, but nothing sounds wrong or in need of additional protection so far.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841355/why-cant-a-malicious-site-obtain-a-csrf-token-via-get-before-attacking/40842990

@nikolayli, No, attackers can not get your CSRF from backend.
